# How to keep your photos in sync with Flickr?

Tags: sync, cloud, shotwell, flickr

I have a ~/photos directory where I keep all my photos. I'd like it to be automatically sync'd to flickr (with their recent generous expansion...) -- all pictures in this directory automatically uploaded to Flickr (visible to me only and without any manipulation/resizing).

Is there a tool for this job? Preferably, not some hacky python script in cron.

Right now, I'm using Shotwell to organise photos. And it works fine. It also has a Flickr plugin but requires the pictures to be "published" manually and doesn't seem to offer any way of organising them once on Flickr. Can it be somehow done with Shotwell?

I would be perfectly happy with uploads happening only when I run Shotwell, or even only when I prompt Shotwell to sync, but so that I don't have to figure out which pictures haven't yet been uploaded.

Comment: Have a look at [dfo](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/09/flickr-apps-desktop-flickr-organizer-application-lets-you-edit-offline-sync-later). `sudo apt-get install dfo`.

Comment: OK, I'm gonna need some handholding here. How do I sync a directory?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a flickr account so I can't help you :/ I might be able to find someone else who *does* have a flickr account though.

Comment: on my opinion dfo is just on a half way. I did try it on Xubuntu, and nothing than errors and exceptions come out of this.

Comment: Desktop flickr organizer seems buggy for me.  This is something that's on the shotwell wishlist (http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/wiki/ShotwellWebServicesWishlist) but the nearest bug report is this http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/2797 , would that be sufficient in the short term?

Comment: You can sync your pics folder to dropbox & then sync dropbox-to-flickr using [wappwolf-dropbox-automator](http://wappwolf.com/dropboxautomator/). **Cons:** its a `one-way` sync & dropbox offers only 5 GB free (it can be extended to 16 GB).

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried [Desktop Flickr Organizer (dfo)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/dfo/)?
It is available in the Software Centre or "[upload photos to Flickr (postr)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/postr/)" package?

I don't use Flickr and have not tested them myself..so give us feedback whether either of them works.

---

OK, now comes the hacky solution. Haven't tested that either :)

Firstly you could look into **[flickrfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/flickrfs.1.html)**. As I understand it enables to create virtual drive through which you can upload/download your files between your Flickr account and Ubuntu.

To enable sync you could use additional application that would sync between your photos folder and that virtual drive. For an example, you could use [rsync](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/unix/nix_rsync/) or [Unison](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Unison) for that. If you go that route then remember to test the virtual drive before you set up the sync.

Might not work and probably painstaking to set up but hopefully works flawlessly ever after.

Comment: I have tried DFO, Frogr, and Shotwell. I haven't seen a sync option in either of those. Doesn't mean it isn't there, I could've missed it, but at the very least it wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 5):

This python script: https://github.com/richq/folders2flickr/ is getting less and less hacky every day...

There has been active resurgence in development as it seemed to be the least "hacky" of the "hacky" options.

The developer is open to suggestions and contributions.

Comment: This only allows uploads it seems, not downloads.

Answer (score 1):

> Try Conduit.
>
> Conduit, a program for the Linux desktop, makes it simple to link your
>   web data, desktop files, and other information all together, then
>   synchronize them all with a single click.
>
> What is Conduit?
>
> Conduit is a synchronization application for GNOME. It allows you to
>   synchronize your files, photos, emails, contacts, notes, calendar data
>   and any other type of personal information and synchronize that data
>   with another computer, an online service, or even another electronic
>   device.
>
> Conduit manages the synchronization and conversion of data into other
>   formats. For example, Conduit allows you to :
>
> - Synchronize your Tomboy notes with another computer
> - Synchronize your your PIM data to your mobile phone, iPod, Nokia    Internet tablet, or between computers
> - Upload photos to Flickr, Picasa, SmugMug, ShutterFly and your iPod
>
> Any combination you can imagine, Conduit will take care of the
>   conversion and synchronization.
>
> Conduit's interface is meant to make data-syncing simple, and, for the
>   most part, it does. Simply drag and drop icons that represent your
>   data in the "cloud" (Flickr photos, YouTube Videos, Box.net backups,
>   etc.) or your actual, physical stuff (files, folders, iPods, data
>   apps) into the "canvas," and start making connections. Add the
>   "sources" of your data first, followed by all the points that will
>   receive it. Right-click on any item in your chain to configure it,
>   whether that means pointing to specific folders or logging into your
>   Flickr, Box.net, or Facebook accounts from pop-up windows.

To install Conduit, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conduit/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install conduit
```

I installed Conduit on Ubuntu 13.04, and it works.  I'm going to assumce that if it worked on 13.04, it will probably work on 12.10, and 12.04.  Now I haven't tried it with flicker, since I don't have an account.

[image]

<sup>Source:[Conduit](https://live.gnome.org/Conduit)</sup>

Comment: Conduit is not available for > karmic(9.10) from that ppa. This project seems to be abandoned long ago. Synchronization doesn't work (or works very poorly) because Flickr recenetly changes its api.

Comment: There is no mention on 9.10 in the question.  I install it on 13.04, and it works.  See additions in the answer above.

Comment: Would let me know if this worked for, just so I'd know.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try jUploadr from http://juploadr.sourceforge.net/.
I used it and it worked very well for me.